# Modify a 2D array in Pascal code

Tags: arrays, optimization, 2d, output, pascal

I have a pascal code and it generates a 2D array that looks like this:

```
    { . . . 1 2 3 . . . . }
    { . . 4 5 6 . . . . . }
    { . 7 8 9 . . . . . . }
    {101112 . . . . . . . }
    {1314 . . . . . . . . }
    {15 . . . . . . . . . }
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
```

Each dot represents a 0 or a empty place that it outputs in my code in 2d array 10x10.

And I need it modify it to generate 2d array like this (may change):

```
    { . . . . . 9 162433. }
    { . . . . 4 10172534. }
    { . . . 2 5 11182635. }
    { . . 1 3 6 12192736. }
    { . . . 4 7 13202837. }
    { . . . . 8 14212938. }
    { . . . . . 15223039. }
    { . . . . . . 233140. }
    { . . . . . . . 3241. }
    { . . . . . . . . 42. }
```

And make it work in one cycle.

Here is the Code that I have written. I am stuck and I need only modify one part of it to generate a new kind of array. It is highlighted here also.

```
    program massiv2;
    const   num=10;   {masiva izmers}
    var
    oper,         { izpildama programmas operacija }
                              { oper=3333 beigt                }
        i,j :   integer;    {darba imdeksi }
        wrk: integer ;
        ms: array[1..num, 1..num] of integer;{array}
     label MENU, BEIGAS;
     begin
     MENU:
writeln;
writeln( 'Programma domata ciklu operatoru un masivu apgusanai ');
writeln( ' 3333 - beigt');
writeln( ' jebkurs cits skaitlis aizpildit masiva prasito dalu ');
writeln( ' ar vertibam 1 2 3 ... pa horizontali ');
read( oper);
if oper=3333 then goto BEIGAS;
{array operation and calcalus }
       for i:=1 to num do
       for j:=1 to num do
  ms[i,j]:=0;
       wrk:=1;                                     
       for i:=1 to 6 do {cycle by rows}          //Modified needed only this part
         begin                                   //
        j:=5-i; if j<1 then j:=1;                //  
        while(j <= 7-i) do {cycle by column}     // 
          begin                                  //  
            ms[i,j]:=wrk;                        // 
            wrk:=wrk+1;                          //  
                                                 // 
             j:=j+1                              //
          end;                                   //
    end;
       for i:=1 to num do  {array output}
         begin writeln;
               for j:=1 to num do
               write( ms[i,j]:7)
         end;
         writeln;   writeln(' Lai turpinatu ievadi jebkuru skaitli ');
         read(j);
        goto MENU;
      BEIGAS:
        end.
```

And how can I make this one kind of 2d array in that code?

```
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
    { . . 212019181716. . }
    { . . . 109 8 7 15. . }
    { . . . . 3 2 6 14. . }
    { . . . . . 1 5 13. . }
    { . . . . . . 4 12. . }
    { . . . . . . . 11. . }
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
    { . . . . . . . . . . }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out how to do the first one here is the line
Works different that wanted but that does it.

```
   j:=3;
   for i:=4 to 10 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=4;
   for i:=4 to 9 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
    j:=4;
   for i:=3 to 8 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
   j:=5;
   for i:=3 to 7 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=5;
   for i:=2 to 6 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=6;
   for i:=2 to 5 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
      j:=6;
   for i:=1 to 4 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=7;
   for i:=1 to 3 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
   j:=7;
   for i:=1 to 2 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
   j:=8;
   for i:=1 to 2 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
    j:=9;
   for i:=1 to 1 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
```

And it looks like this:

```
  0      0      0      0      0     34     41     43     45      0
  0      0      0      0     25     30     35     42     44      0
  0      0      0     14     20     26     31     36     40      0
  0      0      1      8     15     21     27     32     37      0
  0      0      0      2      9     16     22     28     33      0
  0      0      0      0      3     10     17     23     29      0
  0      0      0      0      0      4     11     18     24      0
  0      0      0      0      0      0      5     12     19      0
  0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6     13      0
  0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      7      0
```

Another question is there way how to optimize the code to make it comapact smaller.